# PHP Getting unique values from multidimensional array inside a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get values from a multidimensional array inside a multidimensional array. Here is the multidimensional array...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CalID] => 121111
            [Rink] => North
            [TimeChunks] => Array
                (
                    [int] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 6
                            [1] => 4
                            [2] => 3
                            [3] => 2
                            [4] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CalID] => 121111
            [Rink] => South
            [TimeChunks] => Array
                (
                    [int] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 4
                            [1] => 2
                        )

                )


        )
)
```

I want to get only the valid time chunks from [TimeChunks][int] ie: 1,2,3,4,6,8 but I can't seem to drill down to the second multidimensional array. Here is what I've been trying with no dice:

```
    $tmp = array ();

foreach ($a as $row) 
    if (!in_array($row,$tmp)) array_push($tmp,$row);

print_r ($tmp);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tmp = array();

foreach ($a AS $row) {
  if (isset($row['TimeChunks']['int']) && is_array($row['TimeChunks']['int'])) {
    $tmp = array_merge($tmp, $row['TimeChunks']['int']);
  }
}
$tmp = array_unique($tmp);
```

If the array keys aren't important to you, this should do the trick. It just combines all the values in the different [TimeChunks][int] and then removes the duplicates afterwards.

Comment: `array_merge()` won't cut it here, it will overwrite later values with the same keys because `['int']` is indexed...

Comment: Thx. That worked... Keys are useless to me here. I think the step I was missing was to KISS and jsut remove dupes.

Comment: ['int'] contains numeric keys looking at the example, so should be fine

Answer (score 0):

You're not looping through the array in the 'TimeChunks' key in your array at all, try this:

```
foreach ($a as $row) {
  foreach ($row['TimeChunks'] as $chunk) {
    if (!in_array($row,$chunk)) array_push($tmp,$$chunk);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$tmp = array();
foreach ($array as $section) { // Loop outer array
  if (isset($section['TimeChunks']['int'])) { // make sure ['TimeChunks']['int'] is set for this inner array
    foreach ($section['TimeChunks']['int'] as $chunk) { // Loop the time chunks
      $tmp[] = $chunk; // Push the chunks onto the $tmp array
    }
  }
}
$tmp = array_unique($tmp); // Remove duplicate values

print_r($tmp);
```

You have to loop through the outer array, get the contents of the `['TimeChunks']['int']` key and push that onto the `$tmp` array. You can do an `in_array()` check on each iteration, but it would be more efficient (less function calls) to add them all to the `$tmp` array and pass it through [`array_unique()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

why not use foreach($a as $key=> $value)

then you can use your if statement on the keys and values if you want